# SQL Server SSIS Job step history showing twice

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

There were some T-SQL job steps in SQL Server 2014. I created one SSIS job and inserted as an additional step to be executed only once daily.

When I see `msdb`, it shows it was executed only once but in the history window it is listed twice with the same step number. First it is listed as `sqladmin`'s job and in the next line it is listed under my login.

Any idea?